# Yom Yerushalayim and the seven weeks of sefira

Tags: history, hashkafah-philosophy, sefirat-ha-omer, shavuos, yom-yerushalayim

Commentators in many places have discussed the spiritual ascent that is associated with the seven weeks of sefira, from the time an offering of barley (representing animal feed) is brought, right after we left Egypt, to when we received the Torah (when the leavened *shtei halechem* offering is brought).

Do any commentators discuss specific themes connected to each week of sefira specifically related to events associated with that week, e.g. with regard to this ascent toward Sinai, ? Each week does roughly seem to include/be near at least one significant day, e.g.:

- Week 1: *Yom Hanef* (16 Nisan) from which we count; Shevii shel pesach (21 Nisan) when the sea was split; *Isru Chag* (22 Nisan);
- Week 2: Rosh Chodesh Iyar;
- Week 3: 5 Iyar when the Land of Israel was officially returned;
- Week 4: 15 Iyar - Pesach Sheni - when those who were unable to bring the Pesach, received a 2nd chance;
- Week 5: 18 Iyar - Lag Ba'omer - the plague killing Rabbi Akiva's talmidim stopped;
- Week 6: 28 Iyar - the return of Jerusalem to the Jewish people;
- Week 7: Rosh Chodesh Sivan; Ymei Hagbala.

In particular, do any recent commentators connect the return of Jerusalem to the themes of sefira and Shavuot exactly one week later?

Comment: "Do any commentators discuss specific themes connected to each week of sefira" chesed, gevurah, tiferet, netzach, hod, yesod, malchut

Comment: @wfb if that can be specifically related to events associated with the week, that'd be an answer.